# Android SCSI USB communication issues

Tags: android, usb, scsi

This is not a question about code as much as correct SCSI procedures.

I'm using an open source Android USB library which works fine, but I'm trying to solve some issues with a device I'm having.

When a device is connected the library goes through all its LUNs and calls the following SCSI functions to initialize each one:

1. `INQUIRY`
2. `TEST UNIT READY`
3. `READ CAPACITY`

This works fine on most devices but on my device there is an issue. The device is an SD card reader with two LUNs. One is empty and this results in `TEST UNIT READY` reporting an error when called. `REQUEST SENSE` is then called which reports it as `MEDIUM NOT PRESENT` which is logical and handled by throwing an exception and thereby stopping before `READ CAPACITY` is reached.

The second LUN with an SD card in it also reports an error in `TEST UNIT READY`; `NOT READY TO READY CHANGE, MEDIUM MAY HAVE CHANGED` (Sense code 06h, ASC 28h, ASCQ 00h). I think it essentially means "card inserted". My question is what to do at this point to continue initializing the LUN?

I have tried:

- Calling `TEST UNIT READY` again - results in the exact same error reappearing in `TEST UNIT READY` each time
- Retrying the entire init procedure starting with a new `INQUIRY` - same result as above
- Reading the error and continuing with `READ CAPACITY` - results in the receiving `UsbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer()` for `READ CAPACITY` to return -1.

My conclusion is that either something is wrong with this reader (which seems unlikely) or I'm not handling the further communication with the device correctly after this type of SENSE result is returned. I've been looking through all documentation I can find on google but can't find anything that can help me with this particular issue. I assume some kind of reset or something has to be done? Some way to acknowledge that the medium has changed?

More observations:

- The issue seems to arise only in a certain SD card reader, and only with a certain SD card. Using another SD card in the reader works and using the first SD card in another reader also works.
- When the USB device is initially opened `UsbDeviceConnection.claimInterface(interface, true)` is called. When this takes very long time (1-2 minutes) the issue always arises, but if it has the more normal almost instantaneous delay then the issue doesn't arise.

This leads me to conclude that either this particular SD card and reader doesn't like each other very much, or there is some issue in claimInterface with this particular SD card reader.

Answer (score 1):

The device might be running with `UNIT ATTENTION` interlock.  In this mode, it supports autosense, returning the sense data in response to each command, but it doesn't clear the sense code.  It keeps returning the same one.

If this is what's going on, there are two solutions:

1. You may be able to change behavior this with a `MODE SELECT` of the control mode page by setting the `UA_INTLCK_CTRL` field to 0.  This turns off UA interlock, so that the device clears the status code after reporting it.
2. `REQUEST SENSE` reads and clears a check condition.  You can grind through the status conditions with `REQUEST SENSE` commands until everything is clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually currently run option 2. The sense check always runs one time returning the info and then a second time returning 0 so I take that as all current sense issues has been reported and cleared at that point. Unfortunately the same issue arises as soon as I call `REQUEST SENSE` again. I'm editing the original question with some more observations I've made though.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing everything properly from a SCSI perspective.  Maybe there's something else in the OS that's coming in and resetting the LUN, forcing you to have to repeat the handshake steps?